# How can I control declared namespaces in the xml generated when I serialize an object?

Tags: .net, xml, serialization

I am serializing an object to XML so that it can be passed between two applications.

This was working fine until I modified my class to have a List(of MyCustomType) in it.
Since then, the xml generated has been invalid due to a new tag

```
xsi:type="xsd:string"
```

which gets added to each "value" in a key/value pair that is part of my type.

The invalid section looks like this:

```
<Value xsi:type="xsd:string">ACA04F47-3765-4C39-A698-C4F5B29B057F</Value>
```

An xml editor tells me that the specific error is:

```
The prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:type"
associated with an element type "Value" is not bound.
```

I can overcome this error manually in the xml file by declaring that namespace at the root level of the xml document like so:

```
<MySpecialClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
....
```

So my question is: **how do I get the .net serializer to include that namespace declaration in the xml that it generates?**

The code I am using to do the serialization looks like this:

```
Protected Function SerializedClass(obj As MySpecialClass) As String
    Try
        'serialize the current object as xml and return it as a string
        Dim serializer As New NetDataContractSerializer()
        Dim stream As New MemoryStream()
        serializer.Serialize(stream, obj)
        stream.Position = 0
        Return System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(stream.ToArray())
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: The important thing here is: what does the object itself look like? In thinking Value is typed as "object. - would I be right?

Answer (score 0):

At the class level, it's possible to decorate your object with `XmlRootAttribute` which you can use to define namespace.

To find more information, take a look at the [MSDN Documentation for XmlRootAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hssyycef.aspx).